# Qt for android Linker warnings

Tags: android, qt, linker

When i am trying to deploy my application in a Huawei P9 lite 2017 i am getting linker warnings. For example:

```
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
qt-reserved-files/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
```

The warnings does not showed up when i run the application into a samsung mobile. Any idea?